# Google Cloud Storage in NON-GAE Java app

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this for me, seeing as I am fairly new to using Google Cloud Storage.  Is it possible to use GCS in a non app-engine application, more specifically an application running in Kubernetes in GKE.

Also, how would one spin up a local development version of the storage for testing?  All the examples I can find is app-engine specific, i.e. spinning up the app engine local development server.

Maybe some more context, we want to use this for serving dynamic images, so need fairly low-latency R/W to the storage.

Comment: Yes, you can. There are samples at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api-java-samples , however there is no local equivalent, so all testing is against the Google Cloud Storage. The cloud storage is not low latency (it is using a REST API, there are some projects which provide you with a mountable FS), so in that way it does not seem suitable for your application.

Comment: What are the latency requirements (in milliseconds) that you're targeting?

Comment: @TravisHobrla - Not crazy low, maybe in the sub 50ms range.

Comment: Nico: Latency between end users and GCS, or latency between your application and GCS? If end users, are your users generally in some specific region of the world, or could they be anywhere?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough - No latency between application server and GCS.

Comment: If latency between your application and GCS is a critical factor, you will be best served by running your application from within Google, for example by running your application in GCE or AppEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. While Google Cloud Storage can be used with Google App Engine, it is a standalone service that can be interacted with from anywhere.

If latency and throughput are particularly important to you, it would make a lot of sense for you to run your application which deals directly with Google Cloud Storage from inside the Google Cloud, where it will experience very low latency and can achieve very high throughput. Many GCE applications use GCS, as well as AppEngine apps and Container Engine apps.

When dealing with GCS directly from outside of AppEngine, you will want to use one of our two public APIs, called the [XML](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api-overview) and [JSON APIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/). You could also use one of [many](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/tree/master/gcloud-java-storage) [client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1) [libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary) which invoke those APIs. In addition, for ad-hoc tasks or for experimenting, you can use our command-line client, [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil), as well as our [interactive UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Yes, that clarifies 1 point.  But local development will be a pain if we have to access a GCE instance instead of being able to hit some local version of it.

Comment: AppEngine provides the only local emulation of GCS that I know of. Outside of that, you'll need to invoke the real GCS service or adjust your code to use test stubs or mocks.